# Having multiple AsyncTasks and running multiple ones

Tags: java, android

I have an Asynctask to fill up a ListView already and depending on the selected item
my next step would be download an image from a different url depending on the item selected
would I have to make another private class that extends Asynctask to get the image 
also since I have an itemOnClickListener and if I call .execute() would it cause problems with having multiple Asynctask running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An instance of AsyncTask can only be executed once. If you would like to execute the same AsyncTask multiple times, you'll need to create a new instance for each execution. A common approach to this is:

```
new YourClassExtendingAsyncTask().execute();
```

You may want two classes extending AsyncTask - one to fill your ListView and another to execute in your onItemClickListener to load your images.

For your question about having multiple AsyncTasks running - all AsyncTasks share a single ThreadPool. Android manages this ThreadPool for you, so you can execute multiple AsyncTasks simultaneously without worry.

Hope this helps!

Comment: perfect exactly I just wanted to make sure It could be done that way I wanted to